# close div for the first time and it will not show up again at 10 minutes

Tags: javascript

this is the situation:

**1)** We need to have a box (div) that only shows up when the user has scrolled half the page.

**2)** We want the box to remember if the user closes the box for the first time.
It will not show up again for the user for at least 10 minutes.

Can you help me, i made some code, 
i can close/hide the box but when i scroll down again, it show up again, the box its not really disappear.

Help me complete this without using jquery, pure javascript

my code for close box:

```
function hide()
{
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
};
```

my code for show box when scroll down:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",function()
{
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 800 )
    {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
    }
}, false);
```

if u need the e.g. of html code:

```
<div id="popup" class="popup-container">
    <form action="#" class="popup-form">
    </form>
    <div class="popup-close">
        <span class="fa fa-close" onclick="hide()"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One question: do you need the time count (10 minutes) to be remembered also when the user leave/enter or refresh the site.

Comment: refresh the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let isClicked = false;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    if (!isClicked && window.pageYOffset >= 800) {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
    }
}, false);

function hide() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';

    isClicked = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        isClicked = false;
    }, 10 * 60 * 1000);
};
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #f2f2f2; height: 1200px;">
    Content div
</div>
<div id="popup" class="popup-container">
    <form action="#" class="popup-form">
        POP UP
    </form>
    <div class="popup-close">
        <span onclick="hide()">X</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can do the following things-

1. Keep a variable to store if the box was closed.
   `let isClosed = false;`
   Set its value to true inside `hide()` function.
2. While checking for `scroll offset`, also check for the value of `isClosed`.
   `if(!isClosed && window.pageYOffset >= 800 ){...`
3. Use `setTimeout()` to reset the value of `isClosed` once a timeout is over.

Here is an example of script-

```
let isClosed = false;

function hide() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';

    isClosed = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        isClosed = false;
    }, 10 * 60 * 1000);
};

window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
    if(!isClosed && window.pageYOffset >= 800 ){
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: thank you sir. it work on me. 

just note: when i refresh the page, it reset again and show the box when scroll. but no problem, its a little test for me.

Comment: In that case, you can use `localStorage` in place of the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let localStorage = {};
let minTimeDiffSeconds = 5;
// let minTimeDiffSeconds = 10 * 60;
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
    if(window.pageYOffset >= 800 ){
        let currentTimeSeconds = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        //let timeLastClosed = localStorage.getItem('closedTime')
        let timeLastClosed = localStorage.closedTime;
        let timeDiffSeconds = currentTimeSeconds - timeLastClosed;
        if (timeDiffSeconds > minTimeDiffSeconds) {
            document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
},false);
  
function hide() {
    let currentTimeSeconds = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    //localStorage.setItem('closedTime', currentTimeSeconds);
    localStorage.closedTime = currentTimeSeconds;
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
};
```

```css
.container {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.popup-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
       Permanent Content
  </div>
  <div id="popup" class="popup-container">   
      <form action="#" class="popup-form">
      </form>
      <div class="popup-close">
          <span class="fa fa-close" onclick="hide()">Popup</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use localstorage for this. Store the timestamp when the user closes it, and when the user scrolls, you check if enough time has passed. If yes, then show the popup. Stackoverflow does not allow the use of localstorage, so I have created a localstorage for demo. You can use the browser's localstorage, or the code as is.

Note: For the snippet, I have set the minimum time to be 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Keep a last view time, check that and when it elapses you can reset to visible. When you click the hide, it resets.

Note your scroll will fire a LOT, probably want to de-bounce or throttle that - other questions answer how to do that.
This is not a super fancy version of code to do this...I set this to 1 minute so I could see it work, revise as needed.

```js
var timeLastView;
var hasDelayElapsed = false;
var baseDelay = 1; //minutes to delay

function setViewTime() {
  // convert milliseconds to seconds. 
  timeLastView = (new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
}

function hasTimeElapsed(minutes) {
  var timeCheck = minutes * 60;
  var currentTime = (new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
  if (currentTime - timeLastView >= timeCheck) {
    // then more than 10 minutes elapsed.
    hasDelayElapsed = true;
  } else {
    hasDelayElapsed = false;
  }
  return hasDelayElapsed;
}

function hide() {
  setViewTime();
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
 // lots of logging, probably want to de-bounce this  console.log("scrolling");
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 800 && hasTimeElapsed(baseDelay)) {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.usespace {
  height: 1000px;
}

.popup {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="usespace">Above the thing</div>
<div id="popup" class="popup-container">
  <form action="#" class="popup-form"> something to see here
  </form>
  <div class="popup-close">
    <span class="fa fa-close" onclick="hide()">closer</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="usespace">Howdy below </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

After hiding it, you can use setTimeOut to avoid showing div again for 10 mins. Watch out, 
setTimeOut() params uses miliseconds.

Check it out: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Was that your problem?

Comment: yes sir, i already do that. but when i try it doesn't work.
i hiding it, but no matter how long the time out,
when i scroll down, its appear.

Comment: Well, without your code, a simple way would be to set a boolean variable true from start. When your div disappears, you set it to false and use setTimeOut() to set it true again after 10 minutes, or you can use Date type as well. And your condition would be "if user scrolls to chosen point && bool variable == true".

Comment: i mean:
if(window.pageYOffset >= 800 && tenMinuteCountVariable == true){
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
    }

*You can remove "== true". It was for didatic purposes.

Comment: You can set a new Date(); when you hide it, and then set a date ten minutes later, and then inside your listener compare if ten or more minutes have passed (comparing these two dates). Just a couple ideas. Dont worry, you will succeed anytime. Keep trying.

Comment: Since this is a link only, probably quote the official link https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html

Comment: Is there any better documentation on setTimeout than the sloppy non-community-driven w3schools? Is this a comment or a full-blown answer to OP's question?

Comment: There may be, you can look by yourself if thats not enough for you. Use google.com. Or maybe you can help this guy instead of being a prick. Cheers.